# Default website for Apache2 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, default

heads up – I am still a noobie with the server administration but we have a Virtual Server set up (one IP address) and hosting multiple domains (administration is done through ISP). But I would like to know how to set up a default site to show when our IP (or any website directed to our IPs without actual content on it) is put into browser. Now, when I put our IP into the browser, one of hosted webpages shows and I cannot figure out where to change it. When I trace my ghosts (apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS), i get this:

XX.XX.XX.XX:80       is a NameVirtualHost

```
     default server WEB.COM (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/100-WEB.COM.vhost:6)
     port 80 namevhost WEB.COM (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/100-WEB.COM.vhost:6)
             alias www.WEB.COM
     port 80 namevhost ANOTHER.COM (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/100-ANOTHER.COM.vhost:6)
             alias WWW.ANOTHER.COM
```

– instead of XX.XX.XX.XX (I have our server's IP address)
– WEB.COM is the website (content) showing overtime I target our IP address or domain without content directed to our server
– ANOTHER.COM and so on are other results of DUMP_VHOSTS command

Please, any advice? I've already gone through various posts and possible solutions, but couldn't find the correct one.

Thans in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For a hosting situation like this, I will usually define two additional virtual hosts to specify the "default" site for unbound IPs and the primary IP.

Assume your shared IP for all sites is `1.2.3.4`, create a vhost entry:

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
    ServerName 1.2.3.4
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache/htdocs
    ServerAdmin you@yourdomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

This will make it so access to your server by IP returns the document root specified there instead of some other site.

To then catch any other IPs (you probably don't need this if you only have 1 IP) that are unbound, add:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName hostname.yoursite.com
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache/htdocs
    ServerAdmin you@yourdomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

This should prevent your IP from binding to a random virtual host that you don't want it to.

Comment: Drew, thank you so much. How do I create the vhost entry? Is it best to paste it into 000-default.conf located in /etc/apache2/sites-available or shall I create a new .conf file? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Putting it in the 000-default.conf works fine since it kind of fits in with a default vhost configuration.  You could put it in its own as well.  It doesn't really matter.  They just do it that way for cleanliness but ultimately all of those files get read and merged so it is whatever you prefer.